# Getting checkbox form data when the form is generated by Jinja2

Tags: python, http, flask, http-post, jinja2

I'm trying to make a quiz website. I have a form where the user can select multiple checkboxes at once. I'm using Flask's Jinja2 templating to create the checkboxes. The number of questions per section may change. This is the code for the questions page. The user selects some checkboxes and submits them to the server. How do I know which checkbox was checked since multiple questions share the same name? Is there a better approach to this problem?

```
{% block head %}
<title>Questions Page</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    {% for question in rel%}
    <form action="/questions" method="POST">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1" name="check1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
            {{question}}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Python code:
I'm using a list to store question set title and list of questions.
#hen loaded for the first time, /questions will show the title as "A" and the checkboxes as "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4". After the form is submitted, /questions will show the title as "B" and the checkboxes as "B1" and so on until the list of questions is empty. Is it possible for me to get a list of which questions were checked, like `["A1", "A2"]` for example?

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template,request

app = Flask(__name__)

title = ["A","B"]
rel = [["A1", "A2","A3","A4"], ["B1","B2","B3"]]

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/questions", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def questions():
    if request.method == "GET":
      return render_template('questions.html', rel=rel.pop(0), title=title.pop(0))
    elif request.method == "POST":
       #???
       return str(request.form.getlist('check1')) #This returns a list like [","]
       
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Are the questions on the same page or one question on one page.

Comment: All of them are one page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to add `{{question}}` to the value of the checkbox and I got the list of checkboxes selected with their values.